# R tcltk: title for a tkframe

Tags: r

I think this is a simple question but can't figure it out. I'm trying to build a frame and hoping I can add a title to it. For example, I like to create a slider in a frame. But to identify the frame I'd like to add a title to it. I have no reputation so I can't add a picture, but something like the word "title" below:

--- title --------------------------------

| ===[ ]===================       |

-----.-----------------------------------

Or:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package called rpanel, where somehow the frames are all titled. You might want to look into that one.

Comment: That's exactly where my question came from. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `ttklabelframe` function in the tcltk package.